# While making an array of random integer multiple of n, the program arbitrarily modifies an array

Tags: java, arrays, random

```
    public class Tester {
        public static int randomInt(int low, int high){//this method finds a random integer in between the range of low and high.
            return (int)(Math.random()*(high-low)+low);
        }
        public static int[] randomArray(int[] a){//this method enters those random integers into an array of 100 length.
            for(int i = 0;i<a.length; i++){
                a[i] = randomInt(0, 100);
            }
            return a;
        }
        public static int[] multiple(int[] a, int n){//this method replaces the input array with a new array consisting of (random) multiples of n
            int[] x = new int[100];
            for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
                x[i] = randomArray(a)[i]*n;
            }
            return x;
        }
        public static void list(int[] ints){//this method lists(prints) each indexes in the array in a i(index):ints[i](the random value) format.
            for(int i = 0; i<ints.length; i++){
                System.out.println(i+":"+ints[i]);
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] a = new int[100];
            list(a);// this will yield 1~99:0 since the indexes in the array weren't assigned any values.
        }

}
```

HOWEVER.....

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[100];
        int[] b = multiple(a, 2);
        list(a);//this would instead give me a list of random numbers(0~99:random value) that are not even multiples of 2.
```

This doesn't make sense because `multiple()` method is not supposed to modify the value of `int[] a`. Array a was given a length of 100, with 0 in each indexes as default. Then, array a goes straight into the `list()` method and it shouldn't be altered by the `multiple()` anyhow. The new array given by the `multiple()` is stored in array `b`. Why is this happening? 
        }

Comment: `multiple` calls `randomArray` on `a` `a.length` times, which produces `a.length` new sets of `a.length` random numbers each.

Comment: and that value is stored in b, isn't it?

Comment: Look at your code *for `randomArray`*: It modifies the `a`, which you passed in, in place. You generally want to either just pass in a length and create a new array or modify the parameter in place and not return anything.

Comment: this is giving me a headache.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH!!!!!1111  so basically before, what the multiple method did was that it actually returned the new array while also modifying the existing array!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! So it was a return/void method... well technically

Comment: Not "return/void", but a method *with side effects*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`multiple` calls `randomArray`, which, in turn, modifies the array passed as a parameter:

```
a[i] = randomInt(0, 100);
```

One way to solve this is to remove this method completely, as you always access a single member of the array anyway, and just call `randomInt` directly:

```
public static int[] multiple(int[] a, int n){
    int[] x = new int[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        x[i] = randomInt(0, 100) * n; // Here
    }
    return x;
}
```